# How to add jQuery database plugins?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I searched on [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and found some code to add `dataTable` but that is actually not working is their any different way to add JQuery Datatable Plugin?

I added *cdn* as below inside head tag. My code is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
```

My table:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                `
```

and jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

*instead you added css twice*

please read documentation

> > In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:
>
> code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js
>
> https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**You have missed the datatable js file you need add it:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```